# What's the measure of the segment #An$ in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the triangle $ABC$ ($\angle B = 90^o$) through the point $N$ exterior
of this triangle is drawn $NP$ perndicular to $BC$ ($P$ is the midpoint of $BC$).
Calculate $AN$; if $AB = 3\sqrt29$ and $BC=4\sqrt29$.(Answer:$29$)

My progress:
[image]

Draw $CD$ and $BD$ $\implies \triangle BCD$ (right)

$PC = PD =2\sqrt29$

$\triangle FPD \sim \triangle FBA \implies$

$\frac{FP}{BF}=\frac{FA}{FD}=\frac{3\sqrt29}{3\sqrt29} =\frac{3}{2} $

$\frac{3BF}{2}+BF = 2\sqrt29 \implies BF = \frac{4\sqrt29}{5}\\
\therefore FP = \frac{6\sqrt29}{5}$

$\triangle ABF: (3\sqrt29)^2+(\frac{4\sqrt29}{5})^2 = AF^2\implies AF=\frac{\sqrt{6989}}{5}$

??? I don't think this is the way to go

Comment: It seems like there is no restriction on the point $N$? IE $N$ is any point on the perpendicular of BC? If so, there is no restriction on $AC$. Thus, can you review the question?

Comment: Must $\angle BNC = 90^\circ$? That is stated in the diagram, but not in your writeup.

Comment: If $\angle BNC = 90^\circ$, then $PN = BP = BC/2$. All you need to do is to apply Pythagoras with $(AB+PN)^2 + BP^2 = AN^2$

Comment: @CalvinLin   "P is the midpoint of BC e not BQ..sorry

Comment: @CalvinLin  The question is exactly as in the statement.

Comment: @CalvinLin  The drawing is to scale and the answer is correct as per the geogebra

Comment: @MathLover  Perfect...your relationship is correct but which triangle did you use?  Geogebra gave BNC = 90 but is it possible to demonstrate?

Comment: @petaarantes if it is not given that $\angle BNC = 90^\circ$ then $N$ can be any point on $EF$. How are you deciding where should point $N$ be on $EF$?

Comment: @MathLover   I understood , there is a problem in the question tex, tbut  which triangle did you use in $(AB+PN)^2+BP^2=AN^2 $ ?

Comment: Extend $AB$ and drop a perp from $N$. Say it meets $AB$ at $H$ then right triangle $ \triangle AHN$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the question text so it will be considered that $CN \perp NB$

By Math's hint:

$If ∠BNC=90^∘ \rightarrow  PN=BP=\frac{B}{2}$

Extend AB and drop a perp from N. Say it meets AB at H then right triangle △AHN. –
$\triangle AHN: (AB+PN)^2+BP^2=AN^2\implies
\\ (3\sqrt29+2\sqrt29)^2+(2\sqrt29)^2 = AN^2\\
25\cdot29+4\cdot29=AH^2 \therefore \boxed{AH = 29}$

[image]